# Get caller id and append to url in browser automatically

Tags: windows, usb, phone, dongle, caller-id

I am trying to find a caller id device/program that will automatically open a browser and append the incoming phone number to a url when receiving a call. For example: https://www.myphonesearchapp.com/search?q=5733655593

This would probably be a usb device that you would run a phone line through that will get caller id and allow you to set custom commands like append the number to a url and launching it in a Browser.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to check the log files of the tool you are using to receive the calls ?

Comment: I haven't purchased the tool yet because I am still in the research phase.

Comment: the look for a tool that generates a log and then you need to write a script that would read the log file and do as you need

Comment: Right that is mostly what I was looking for help with. Finding the tool that would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a program, called CallClerk, that does this (I wrote it).  In short you simply need to turn on the reverse look up function and after that when a call comes in your browser will open with the url you define.   For more information please see: http://www.callclerk.com/phone/hlpCallClerkSettingsReverseLookup.html

Of course you also need a modem that reports caller id (you can get these for about $10) and subscribe to a caller id service with your phone company.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some [scripting tools and utilities](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd823314) provided by windows specially the log parser

Answer (score 0):

If you have a serial-attached external voice modem, it's not overly difficult to do this under Linux.  I do believe `vgetty` will listen to a tty (`ttyS0`, etc.) and do things when an incoming call is received.  So you basically write a small script that is called by `vgetty` and have it pop open a browser.  I'm sketchy on the details because it's been a long time since I've messed with it.

I believe the majority of 56k fax/voice/data modems can read Caller ID.  As far as getting one, check your local mom-and-pop computer parts store for an old musty external modem in the back.